# Как сделать взаимодействие с предметами на E в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Например, у меня есть объект двери и при нажатии на E с определённого близкого расстояния эта дверь должна открываться по нажатию клавиши E. Как это можно реализовать?
C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно понимаю, что вам нужно открыть дверь, если расстояние между игроком и дверью меньше какого-то расстояния икс?
Если да, то вам нужно принять нажатие на клавишу E, после чего измерить расстояние и при условии, что расстояние меньше какого-то X, открыть дверь.

```
private void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
        if (Vector3.Distance(MainCharacter.transform.position, Door.transform.position) <= нужное_расстояние)) {
            // Открытие двери
        }
    }
}
```

Функция [Vector3.Distance(Vector3 a, Vector3 b)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) возвращает расстояние между двумя точками в пространстве.